# Getting the last element of a split string array

Tags: javascript, split

I need to get the last element of a split array with multiple separators. The separators are commas and space. If there are no separators it should return the original string.

If the string is "how,are you doing, today?" it should return "today?"

If the input were "hello" the output should be "hello".

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```js
const str = "hello,how,are,you,today?"
const pieces = str.split(/[\s,]+/)
const last = pieces[pieces.length - 1]

console.log({last})
```

At this point, `pieces` is an array and `pieces.length` contains the size of the array so to get the last element of the array, you check `pieces[pieces.length-1]`. If there are no commas or spaces it will simply output the string as it was given.

```
alert(pieces[pieces.length-1]); // alerts "today?"
```

Comment: You could also use `pieces.pop()` to get the last item of your array.

Comment: is there a way to use this to refer back to str.split() without having to store the variable?

Comment: `var last = str.split(/[\s,]+/).pop()`

Answer (score 1020):

There's a one-liner for everything. :)

```
var output = input.split(/[, ]+/).pop();
```

Comment: Issue here is that pop() also *removes* that element from the array, thereby changing it.

Comment: @Jangla: That's not a problem, as the array is created by the `split` call, it's not kept anyway. The original string is not changed by popping the item from the array.

Comment: brilliant, all in one go, no need for intermediary var to setup the array...nice

Comment: @Guffa Do you know how can I get last two elements of split?

Comment: @VitorGuerreiro: Yes, you can use the `slice` method: `var output = input.split(/[, ]+/).slice(-2);`.

Comment: What's the purpose of the '+' ?

Comment: @MarioLevrero: That's a quantifier that means the same as the quantifier `{1,}`, i.e. `[, ]+` matches one or more of the characters in the set (comma and space). It's useful when you want all the words from the string, but when you only want the last word it doesn't make any functional difference, it only reduces the overhead as there will be fewer strings in the array.

Answer (score 110):

```
var item = "one,two,three";
var lastItem = item.split(",").pop();
console.log(lastItem); // three
```

Comment: I don't think pop() takes arguments.

Comment: @GraceShao: yep. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: But, generically speaking `.split(',').pop()` works for last element on comma separated string. Just sayin' cuz I was misled by Guffa's awesome answer, I just disregarded it because didn't need a regex and thought the trick was there! :P

Answer (score 42):

Best one ever and my favorite using `split` and `slice`

```js
const str = "hello, how are you today?"
const last = str.split(' ').slice(-1)[0]
console.log({last})
```

And another one is using `split` then `pop` the last one.

```js
const str = "hello, how are you today?"
const last = str.split(' ').pop()
console.log({last})
```

Comment: Ah of course. This is a great answer because it doesn't mutate the original +1

Comment: using `.pop()` is still a nice convenience after slice.. no mutation since the accessor method returns a new array.

Answer (score 34):

You can also consider to reverse your array and take the first element. That way you don't have to know about the length, but it brings no real benefits and the disadvantage that the reverse operation might take longer with big arrays:

```
array1.split(",").reverse()[0]
```

It's easy though, but also modifies the original array in question. That might or might not be a problem.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Probably you might want to use this though:

```
array1.split(",").pop()
```

Comment: The `.pop()` method is the best answer I've seen so far. That's why it was created!

Comment: I'd strongly advise against reverse() because reversing will be expensive on large arrays. If you don't care about mutation, simply use pop(), otherwise slice(-1)[0].

Comment: its increasing the time complexity since you have an extra loop to reverse the array.

Answer (score 7):

The `at()` method takes an integer value and returns the item at that index, allowing for positive and negative integers. Negative integers count back from the last item in the array.

```js
const str = "how,are you doing, today?";
const last = str.split(/[\s,]+/).at(-1);
console.log({last});
```

Link to documentation: [`Array.prototype.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

Comment: thats new and convenient ^_^

Answer (score 5):

This way is easy to understand and very short.

```
const output = input.split(',').pop().split(' ').pop();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to get last elements

```js
let input='one,two,three,four';

let output1 = input.split(',').pop();
console.log('output1 =',output1);

let split = input.split(',');
let output2 = split[split.length-1];
console.log('output2=',output2);

let output3 = input.split(',').reverse()[0];
console.log('output3=',output3);

let output4 = input.split(',').slice(-1)[0];
console.log('output4=',output4);
```

Answer (score 3):

And if you don't want to construct an array ...

```
var str = "how,are you doing, today?";
var res = str.replace(/(.*)([, ])([^, ]*$)/,"$3");
```

The breakdown in english is:

```
/(anything)(any separator once)(anything that isn't a separator 0 or more times)/
```

The replace just says replace the entire string with the stuff after the last separator.

So you can see how this can be applied generally. Note the original string is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
var title = 'fdfdsg dsgdfh dgdh dsgdh tyu hjuk yjuk uyk hjg fhjg hjj tytutdfsf sdgsdg dsfsdgvf dfgfdhdn dfgilkj,n, jhk jsu wheiu sjldsf dfdsf hfdkdjf dfhdfkd hsfd ,dsfk dfjdf ,yier djsgyi kds';
var shortText = $.trim(title).substring(1000, 150).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...More >>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array index directly:

`var csv = 'zero,one,two,three';
csv.split(',')[0]; //result: zero
csv.split(',')[3]; //result: three`

Comment: Hello tnong, welcome to SO! I think this answer does not take the space separator into account as requested in the question.

Comment: This answer does not support arbitrary string array length