# How to Get File Name from Upload Form Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, upload, filenames

I want to get the file name of the uploaded file using jQuery. But the problem, I got the fake path and file name, instead of the file name only. This is my form.

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" /> 
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="inputSubmit" />
</form>
```

And the jQuery is like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#inputSubmit').click(function(){
      alert($('#uploadFile').val());
    });
});
```

I use Chrome and got this in the alert box. Let's say I choose file named filename.jpg.

```
C:\fakepath\filename.jpg
```

How can I get only the file name? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Split the filepath string with "\" and use the last item in the resulting array.

see: [Getting the last element of a split string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651563/get-the-last-element-of-a-splitted-string-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

You can also do:

```
$('#uploadFile').prop("files")['name'];
```

If it's a multiple file input, do:

```
$.each($('#uploadFile').prop("files"), function(k,v){
    var filename = v['name'];

    // filename = "blahblah.jpg", without path
});
```

Comment: I think this is the proper way of using for single file
`$('#uploadFile').prop("files")[0]['name'];`

Answer (score 2):

get file name when uploading using jquery

`var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\').pop();`