# how to determine highest resolution image from srcset

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, url, srcset

Say i have an image as

```
<img srcset="large.jpg 1400w, medium.jpg 700w, small.jpg 400w"
     sizes="(min-width: 700px) 700px, 100vw"
     alt="A woman reading">
```

Now this can also be in a format like

```
<img srcset="large.jpg 2x, medium.jpg 1.3x, small.jpg 0.8x"
     sizes="(min-width: 700px) 700px, 100vw"
     alt="A woman reading">
```

<strike>Also, (Not a valid HTML)</strike>

```
<img srcset="large.jpg 1400w, medium.jpg 1.3x, small.jpg 0.8x"
     sizes="(min-width: 700px) 700px, 100vw"
     alt="A woman reading">
```

Now how do i extract URL that has the highest resolution image.
I thought of splitting the srcset and then extracting the size but the problem is that sizes can be in `1200w` format or in `2x` format or in both of them and i don't know how to distinguish whether this is the `1200w` format or `2x` format and even if i do find out what's what, how do i compare them for determining the biggest size.

I wish i could show what i've tried but there is nothing coming to my head about how to do this!

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: Also, why can't you assume it's the first item in the list?

Comment: @JanDvorak XY problem?? I've to inject a script on user's page and then show him images available on the page separately in  a popup. Now i can use SRC simply but it would give me the default image however i want to get the best picture available.

Comment: @JanDvorak Is it necessary that the first one would be the biggest one?

Comment: @JanDvorak whether it's an XY problem isn't relevant, as long as the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all your HTML code is invalid because you can not mix `x` and `w` descriptors for `srcset`. Pick one but not both.

**1)** You can't know which image is bigger unless you download them all, of course you may - when supported server side - perform an `HEAD` request for each image and check `Content-Length` header property. It's not easy and what you get is just image size in bytes, not its dimensions but it's a good approximation. Roughly something like this:

```
var sizes = [];

// Peform this for each UR...
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: imageUrl,
    success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
        sizes.push({
            url: imageUrl,
            size: parseInt(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
        });
    }
});
```

You can obtain URLs simply splitting `srcset` attribute and ignoring size part (I'm sure someone with better knowledge about regex can do something better):

```
var urls = srcset.replace(/\s+[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[wx]/g, "").split(/,/);
```

Calls may be done in parallel or - more easily IMO - sequentially using queues and `$(document).queue()` jQuery method.

This can't be always done (maybe because server doesn't accept `HEAD` or image sizes are too similar because of compression and/or aspect ratios) then you have to *parse* `srcset` attribute.

**2)** Let's first see a **proof of concept** (read as: it's not complete nor efficient) of what you may do for pixel density descriptor `x`: split with over white space `.split(/ /)` and then pick biggest one.

```
// Read value from tag...this is just for testing
var srcset = "small.jpg 0.8x, large.jpg 1.5x, medium.jpg 1.3x";

var biggestImage = "";
var highestPixelDensity = 1;

for (var descriptor of srcset.split(/,/)) {
    var parts = descriptor.trim().split(/ /);

    // Here we check only for pixel density, see later for
    // width descriptor but code is straightforward
    var pixelDensity = parseFloat(parts[1].substring(-1));
    if (pixelDensity > highestPixelDensity) {
        biggestImage = parts[0];
        highestPixelDensity = pixelDensity;
    }
}
```

Things are different for width descriptor `w` because it relates to `sizes` then  you first need to determine which one is applied. It's little bit more convoluted but it's easy to do with `window.matchMedia()` (again it's not complete code but an illustrative proof of concept):

```
// Read this from tag...
var sizes = "(min-width: 800px) 700px, (min-width: 700px) 300px";

for (var descriptor of sizes.split(/,/)) {
    // Love this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/651646/1207195
    var imageSize = descriptor.split(/[, ]+/).pop();

    // You still need to handle last item special case (where there is not media query).
    var mediaQuery = descriptor.substring(-imageSize.length);

    // You can stop with first matched media query, you have your required imageSize
    var isMatch = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches;
}
```

Now you have required size (check its unit and convert it appropriately, for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28295133/1207195)) and you're done to use it with width descriptor extracted from `srcset`.

Note that you don't know which image is bigger unless you download it. What you can assume is that higher pixel density `x` or higher width descriptor `w` (but it **must** be calculated in relation to `sizes` attribute content, bigger screen uses bigger image) will give you the bigger one. Of course it's an assumption then it may fail in some cases. To determine which one must be used is simply:

```
var isPixelDensity = srcset.trim().substr(-1) === "x";
```

Just...put those samples together, handle missing corners cases, basic error handling and browser specific issues and you're done...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this<br>
But sorry i didn't get the last line. What i understood is if my screen size matches with the `mediaQuery` then that's the one i need. And if i got it right then i'm afraid i don't need that but the LARGEST/BIGGEST image irrespective of the `mediaQuery`. How do i do that?

Comment: You don't know _exact_ image size unless you download them all but you can **assume** that bigger image will be used for bigger screens (width...) then when you have a candidate size (from sizes attribute) you will pick the one with bigger width (from srcset attribute). For width descriptors those attributes work together (but sizes can be ignored for pixel density)

Comment: Was wondering if you can help me [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930597/how-pinterest-extension-store-temporarily-images-from-a-web-page-and-then-acce) as well...?

Comment: Give a chance to DelightedD0D to post an answer but you may want to take a look to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4177803/1207195. Not _so_ easy but possible without extensions (unless it's OK for you to manage their deploy and to limit to Chrome)

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I use :

```js
static getHighestResImg(element) {
  if (element.getAttribute("srcset")) {
    return element
      .getAttribute("srcset")
      .split(",")
      .reduce(
        (acc, item) => {
          let [url, width] = item.trim().split(" ");
          width = parseInt(width);
          if (width > acc.width) return { width, url };
          return acc;
        },
        { width: 0, url: "" }
      ).url;
  }

  return element.getAttribute("src");
}
```

Comment: This solution obviously doesn’t work if any of the image URLs contain a comma

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same for wordpress images generated and relevant `srcset`

Wordpress creates the `srcset` in a way that the smaller image comes first and then it keeps on increasing until it gets the biggest image in `srcset`.

Sample image code generated by wordpress:

```
<img width="300" height="221" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Sharon-Ron-Chip-300x221.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-medium" alt="" srcset="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Sharon-Ron-Chip-300x221.jpg 300w, http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Sharon-Ron-Chip-768x566.jpg 768w, http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Sharon-Ron-Chip-1024x755.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
```

also, in some cases when the image is too small, then wordpress does not create `srcset` attribute at all.

So, this is what i did: (CHANGE `my_image_class_to_target` in the code to your required target class)

```
jQuery('img.my_image_class_to_target').each(function () {
    var mysrcset = jQuery(this).attr('srcset');
    if (typeof mysrcset !== 'undefined'){ //checking if the srcset attribute is defined
        lastsrcset = mysrcset.split(',');
        lastsrc = lastsrcset[(lastsrcset.length - 1)];
        lastpuresrc = lastsrc.split(' ');
        mysrc = lastpuresrc[1];

    } else { //when srcset is not defined in case of small images
    var mysrcset = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        mysrc = mysrcset;
    }

    // display or use src of biggest image src
    console.log(mysrc);

});
```

I am new to Javascript/jQuery, so please forgive if i have taken a longer route. ;)

Any additions/ updates to code are welcome.

Comment: This will fail when the url has a comma in it, sadly