# scan string until element in another list is not found, then split

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Say I have the following string

```
s = "DH3580-Fr1-TRG-TRB-DH1234-Fr3"
```

and I have a list of characters

```
l = ['Fr1', 'TRG', 'TRB', 'SOUL']
```

Excluding the string upstream of the first `-` (`DH3580`), I want to scan `s` until it finds the last element which is present in `l`, in this case `TRB`. Finally I want to split the string `s` by the immediate `-` thereafter. So that `s` becomes the list

```
['DH3580-Fr1-TRG-TRB', 'DH1234-Fr3']
```

What would be the best way to do this in python3?

There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651563/getting-the-last-element-of-a-split-string-array?rq=2), although for JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first split your text into individual items, then make an iterator out of it. I did this because I need it to be exhausted in order to later get the rest of the text.

```py
l = ["Fr1", "TRG", "TRB", "SOUL"]
s = "DH3580-Fr1-TRG-TRB-DH1234-Fr3"

first, *rest = s.split("-")

rest_iterator = iter(rest)
res = [first]
first_excluded_item = None
for part in rest_iterator:
    if part in l:
        res.append(part)
    else:
        first_excluded_item = part
        break

if first_excluded_item:
    rest = [first_excluded_item, *rest_iterator]
else:
    rest = list(rest_iterator)
print(["-".join(res)] + ["-".join(rest)])
```

output:

```
['DH3580-Fr1-TRG-TRB', 'DH1234-Fr3']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many undefined requirements in your question (e.g. would elements in `s` and `l` be ordered?), but maybe this solution would work:

```py
def indices(list1, list2):
    idx = []
    for l2 in list2:
        if l2 in list1:
            idx.append(list1.index(l2))
    return idx

s = 'DH3580-Fr1-TRG-TRB-DH1234-Fr3'
l = ['Fr1', 'TRG', 'TRB', 'SOUL']

tokens = s.split('-')
imax = indices(tokens, l)[-1]  # index of the last matching elements

['-'.join(tokens[:imax+1]), '-'.join(tokens[imax+1:])]  # [up to matching, remainder]
# ['DH3580-Fr1-TRG-TRB', 'DH1234-Fr3']
```